# How to cast a C# nullable Enum to int in c++/CLI

Tags: enums, c++-cli, nullable

I would like to cast a C# nullable enum into an int.

For now, I have something like:

c#

```
public enum Dir
{
 Up = 0,
 Down = 1,
 Left = 2,
 Right = 3
}
```

c++/cli

```
function(System::Nullable<Dir> d){
   if(d != NULL){
       (int)d; error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Nullable<T>' to 'int' 
   }
}
```

So, how to cast a nullable enum ?
There is no such nullable int c++/CLI or ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to test for null (C++/CLI won't let you compare against `nullptr`, for some reason), and you can use [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to retrieve the value, which can then be cast to integer.

```
void function(System::Nullable<Dir> d){
   if(d.HasValue){
       int i = (int)d.Value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the value of the `Nullable<T>` with the `.Value` property, and cast that to `int`.

*Disclaimer: I've never used C++/CLI*